# DBT macro for repetitive task

Tags: dbt

I am a beginner in DBT. I have a requirement where I have created an Incremental model like below. I need to execute the same Incremental model logic statements for different systems.

There are 3 variables or parameters that I need to pass. i.e. for each run the `ATTRIBUTE_NAME`, `VIEW_NAME`, `SYSTEM_NAME` will need to be passed. For the next run, all the 3 parameters would be different.

However, for a particular `SYSTEM_NAME`, the `VIEW_NAME` and `ATTRIBUTE_NAME` are fixed.

Please help me to execute the dbt run using a macro for this requirement and pass the different system names and their corresponding view names and attribute names. Objective is to use single dbt run statement and execute this model for all ATTRIBUTE_NAME, VIEW_NAME, SYSTEM_NAME.

For now, I have defined variable and execute each run separately for each systems like below in CLI

e.g.

```
dbt run --vars '{"VIEW_NAME": CCC, "SYSTEM_NAME": BBBB, "ATTRIBUTE_NAME": AAAA}' -m incremental_modelname
```

```
dbt run --vars '{"VIEW_NAME": DDD, "SYSTEM_NAME": FFF, "ATTRIBUTE_NAME": HHH}' -m incremental_modelname
```

```
dbt run --vars '{"VIEW_NAME": EEE, "SYSTEM_NAME": GGG, "ATTRIBUTE_NAME": III}' -m incremental_modelname
```

**Re-usuable Incremental model:**

```sql
{{ 
    config(
        materialized='incremental', 
        transient=false, 
        unique_key='composite_key',  
        post_hook="insert into table (col1, col2, col3)
                        select 
                            '{{ var('ATTRIBUTE_NAME') }}',
                            col2, 
                            col3 
                        from {{ this }}  a
                        join table b on a=b
                        where b.SYSTEM_NAME='{{ var('SYSTEM_NAME') }}';
                         commit;"
    ) 
}}


with name1 AS (
    select 
        *
    from {{ var('VIEW_NAME') }}
),

select 
    *
from name1

{% if is_incremental() %}

where (select timestamp_column from {{ var('VIEW_NAME') }}) > 
    (select max(timestamp_column) from {{ this }} where SYSTEM_NAME='{{ var("SYSTEM_NAME") }}')
                             
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to:

1. Create a model(or even a seed) that holds the system name, view name and attribute name.
2. Within your code, add a for loop

   ```
    {% set query %}
    select system_name, view_name, attribute_name from model_name
    {% endset %}

    {% set results = run_query(query) %}

    {% for result in results %}

        /*
        Put your query here but reference the columns needed 
        results.columns[0].values()  = system_name
        results.columns[1].values()  = view_name
        results.columns[2].values()  = attribute_name
        */
   ```